# How can I debug Eigen alignment errors when they seem unrelated to the exact code which triggers them

Tags: c++, g++, alignment, clang++, eigen3

I am writing code which uses the Eigen matrix library for coordinate transforms, and also PCL for point cloud processing (which also uses Eigen a lot). I keep getting assertion errors from Eigen, about unaligned accesses, despite the fact that I have observed everything in the documentation about alignment of Eigen types (https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__DenseMatrixManipulation__Alignement.html).

I can only trigger this assertion when some Eigen code has run before, but was unsuccessful in pinpointing what the exact conditions are. For instance, this is the code that crashes:

```
Affine3f Transform::getAffine() const {
    // ... Vector3f translation(...)
    // ... Quaternionf rotation(...)
  Affine3f affine = Affine3:f:Identity(); /// <--- 
  affine.translate(translation);
  affine.rotate(rotation);
  return affine;
}
```

but only if some eigen code has been executed before. Maybe that is because the problem only arises after some allocations made by the `Eigen::aligned_allocator`.

However, the help pages tell me I should use a debugger to check exactly which object has unaligned:

> For example, if you're using GCC, you can use the GDB debugger as follows:

```
$ gdb ./my_program          # Start GDB on your program
> run                       # Start running your program
...                         # Now reproduce the crash!
> bt                        # Obtain the backtrace
```

> Now that you know precisely where in your own code the problem is happening, read on to 
>   understand what you need to change.

I am of course doing that, but the code crashing here seems to satisfy all the requirements.

## Question

How can I effectively debug what code causes the misalignment when the error is only triggered during later allocations?

Comment: You might use a memory debugger such as [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) to see if it reports anything. And of course don't forget to build with lots of warnings enabled to see if the compiler itself catches anything. And perhaps even use some static analyser which can go deeper than the compiler typically does.

Comment: Good suggestion. I am not experienced with static analyzers; can you recommend one?

Comment: I'm sorry but I haven't used one myself for some time, so I don't know what exists these days. Shouldn't be too hard to "google" though.

Comment: Did you check the suggestions for making a [mre]? One path that often works is to start removing parts of your code until the problem disappears (then re-insert them and remove other parts).

Comment: Of course, that's what I did, but I could never reproduce it with anything that could be called "minimal".

Comment: MRE does not have to be smaller than some threshold. Just keep removing parts which are not required to reproduce the issue. Regarding valgrind (as recommended by @Someprogrammerdude), on most linuxes you can install that via the packet-management (`sudo apt install valgrind`, or similar) and then just run `valgrind ./my_program`. You can check `man valgrind` or `valgrind -h` (or google) for possible options.